# php $_get function not working

Tags: php, get

My `php $_get` function is not working. Here is the code I tried:-

```
       <?php
        $user = $_get["user"];
            echo "Hello $user ! Great to have you here <br/> ";
        for($i=1; $i<10; $i++)
        {
        echo "This text is from php";
        }

            ?>
```

when I type this in the URL `http://localhost/for.php?user=me,me` is not shown in the output.

Can you help please?

Comment: Do yourself a favour and check for `isset` or `!empty` first. `$user = (isset($_GET["user"]) ? $_GET["user"] : null);` would not result in warnings/notices if the GET param wasn't set.

Comment: It's **`$_GET`**, not `$_get`. It's **not** a function, but a super-global variable. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Comment: Your echo should also be : echo"Hello" . $user . "! Great... ";

Answer (score 11):

`$_get` is case sensitive. It needs to be [`$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

Also, `$_GET` is not a function, it's a [**Superglobal**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).

Comment: And it also isn't function.

Comment: It's a [super global array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

Answer (score 2):

`$_get["user"]` must be `$_GET["user"]` and its not a function its a superglobal array...

For more check [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) of $_GET

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <?php
    $user = $_GET["user"];
        echo "Hello ".$user." ! Great to have you here <br/> ";
    for($i=1; $i<10; $i++)
    {
    echo "This text is from php";
    }
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $user = $_GET["user"];
        echo "Hello $user ! Great to have you here <br/> ";
    for($i=1; $i<10; $i++)
    {
    echo "This text is from php";
    }
```

Use proper name of method.